# Oracle 12c send notification on insert/update/delete

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My company has **oracle 12c.** We are looking for a way to send notification to the server, on **insert/update/delete**. I know this may not be an ideal, but I was strictly instructed to go this route. I know we have Database Change Notification(DCN) with Oracle 11g. Can this be done on oracle 12c also ? Would be great if anyone could give me pointers on how to approach this.

Comment: Why do you think change notification was removed in 12c?

Comment: I'm not sure! why? I'm new to oracle 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database Change Notification was removed from Oracle Database 12c.  The link below details the removal of the feature, see section 2.2.1:

http://oradb-srv.wlv.ac.uk/E50529_01/READM/chapter12102.htm

To do what you want would require another method.  I would suggest that you check Database Auditing.  More information on that can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000

You can set up auditing right down to a column in a table if you want and send out an email when the data changes right from the database.

Comment: Thank you, I will go through the documentation.  Is it possible to do it  I do it through triggers? I found this documentation online.

https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043795-can-i-publish-a-message-via-a-database-trigger

Comment: It's possible with Update and Insert triggers.  Don't see why not.  I don't do it that way, I audit.  There is a built-in java function to send email directly from the database, no reason that I can think of that you couldn't tie the two together.